# Scala test match case classes on some field

Tags: scala, scalatest

I have

```
case class Foo(field1: String, field2: String, field3: String)

expected: Seq[Foo] = Seq(...)

result: Seq[Foo] = Seq(...)
```

I want to write a Scala matcher that compare the elements of Seq without taking in consideration field1.

So two elements will match if field2 and field3 are equals. Field1 value is not considerated.

Example:

```
val expected = Seq(
  Foo(
    "f1", "f2", "f3"
  )
)

val result = Seq(
  Foo(
    "fx", "f2", "f3"
  )
)
```

This two sequence has to match.

```
  result should matchWithoutId(expected)
```

Comment: Maybe this is a sign that your model contains data that shouldn't be there?

Answer (score 3):

The documentation is in [Using custom Matchers](https://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_matchers#usingCustomMatchers), this example would be (for example)

```
def matchWithoutId(expected: Foo): Matcher[Foo] = Matcher { actual =>
  MatchResult(
    actual.field2 == expected.field2 && actual.field3 == expected.field3,
    if (actual.field2 != expected.field2)
      s"field2 of $actual was not equal to that of $expected"
    else
      s"field3 of $actual was not equal to that of $expected",
    s"field2 and field3 of $actual were equal to those of $expected")
}
```

Adjust error messages to taste.

Or another approach (probably a better one in this case):

```
def matchWithoutId(expected: Foo): Matcher[Foo] = have(
  'field2 (expected.field2),
  'field3 (expected.field3)
)
```

Normally I'd say using Symbols to name properties and use reflection should be avoided, but here a change to `Foo` will make the tests fail to compile anyway because of access to `expected`'s fields.

EDIT: I missed that you want to compare `Seq[Foo]`s and not `Foo`s, so Mario Galic's answer is probably the one you want. Still, this can hopefully be useful as well.

Comment: the cons of this solution is that if a field is added to the case class, we have to add the condition in the matcher.

Comment: Then the second solution won't work, yes, but the first one can be modified to use `actual.copy(field1 = 0) == expected.copy(field1 = 0)`.

Answer (score 2):

[Working with "sequences"](https://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_matchers#workingWithSequences) states

> if you want to change how containership is determined for an element
>   type E, place an implicit `Equality[E]` in scope or use the explicitly
>   DSL.

so the following should work

```
(expected should contain theSameElementsAs (result)) (decided by fooEqualityWithoutId)
```

Note about `contains` usage

> Note that when you use the explicitly DSL with `contain` you need to
>   wrap the entire contain expression in parentheses

Here is the full example

```
import org.scalactic._
import org.scalatest._
import org.scalatest.matchers.should.Matchers
import org.scalactic.Explicitly._

class CustomizeEqualitySeqSpec extends FlatSpec with Matchers with Explicitly {
  case class Foo(field1: String, field2: String, field3: String)
  val expected = Seq(Foo("f1", "f2", "f3"))
  val result = Seq(Foo("fx", "f2", "f3"))

  val fooEqualityWithoutId = new Equality[Foo] {
    override def areEqual(a: Foo, b: Any): Boolean = b match {
      case Foo(_, field2, field3) => a.field2 == field2 && a.field3 == field3;
      case _ => false
    }
  }

  "Sequences" should "use custom Equality[E]" in {
    (expected should contain theSameElementsAs (result)) (decided by fooEqualityWithoutId)
  }
}
```